# cURL - cookies and sessions

Tags: php, curl

Im using cURL to log into a website and then store a session cookie.

Is there a way I can access that session cookie from another PHP script (in the same dir etc.) Ive tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo $content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But that doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this as well, to read the file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

complete code:

```
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo $content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

have fun!