# set language in html dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I am scrpping data from a site, which is by default in french and have english version as well. The problem is when I scrap data from it, it return html in french, there is not paramter set for english in URL, so I can add that. I have tried this in html tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/" lang="en" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

and

```
<body id="lang-en" class="site-duproprio  prov-QC">
```

But no luck. Here is the website from where I want to scrap data.

```
http://duproprio.com/search/?hash=/g-re=13/s-filter=forsale/pa-ge=1/
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This site keeps language in session. So before you want to scrape data in english you must visit http://duproprio.com/gotoen

If you use cURL then this is a relevant question [cURL - cookies and sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096848/curl-cookies-and-sessions).

Comment: Damnit I was just about to submit almost exactly the same answer :(

Comment: I have to visit the site using curl in order to make cookies? and the again get the data through curl and include that cookie file?